# How to get string without the last N characters?

Tags: bash, awk

If I have a bash string in a variable. **How do I extract/retrieve that string except for the last character,** and how easy would it be if I want to extract until the last two characters?

Example:

```
# Removing the last character
INPUT="This is my string."
# Expected output "This is my string"

# Removing the last two characters
INPUT="This is my stringoi"
# Expected output "This is my string"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample:

```
INPUT="This is my string."
echo $INPUT |sed 's/.$//' # removes last character

INPUT="This is my stringoi"
echo $INPUT |sed 's/..$//' # removes last two character
```

Comment: Maybe you should also show an example with intervals like `s/.\{3\}$//`

Comment: Yes, the same will also work, Thanks for notifying..!! @oguzismail

Answer (score 8):

With any POSIX shell:

```
OUTPUT="${INPUT%?}"  # remove last character
OUTPUT="${INPUT%??}" # remove last two characters
                     # and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Adding a generic solution here. You can mention number of characters which you want to remove from end of line in `awk` named `remove_char` and it should work accordingly then.

```
awk -v remove_char="2" '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-remove_char)}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}' Input_file
```

---

---

2nd solution: making field separator none with GNU `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {NF--} 1' Input_file
```